# More $a^3+b^3+c^3=(c+1)^3,$ and $\sqrt[3]{\cos\tfrac{2\pi}7}+\sqrt[3]{\cos\tfrac{4\pi}7}+\sqrt[3]{\cos\tfrac{8\pi}7}=\sqrt[3]{\tfrac{5-3\sqrt[3]7}2}$

Tags: number-theory, diophantine-equations, cubics, parametrization

**I. Solutions**

In a previous post, [On sums of three cubes of form $a^3+b^3+c^3=(c+1)^3$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4776322/4781), an example of which is the well-known,

$$3^3+4^3+5^3=6^3$$

we asked if there were polynomial parameterizations *higher than 3rd degree*. The answer was in the **affirmative**. In this new question, we ask if more "triplet parameterizations" can be found. These "triplets" will be described below.

First, the equation $a^3+b^3+c^3=(c+1)^3$ can be solved as a quadratic in $c$, namely,

$$c =  \frac{-3+\sqrt{12(a^3+b^3)-3}}6$$

Hence the condition is akin to an elliptic curve,

$$P(a,b):=12(a^3+b^3)-3 = y^2$$

but is to be solved by integer polynomials. ***Ten*** solutions have been found so far, the first three being,

$$a_1 = n,\quad b_1 = 3n^2+2n+1$$

$$a_{2,3} = 3n^2, \quad b_{2,3} = 6n^2\pm3n+1\quad$$

The next three found by Old Peter and based on,

$$(\color{blue}{9n^3})^3 + (\color{blue}{-9n^3 + 9n^2 - 3n + 1})^3 + (27n^4 - 18n^3 + 9n^2 - 3n)^3 = (27n^4 - 18n^3 + 9n^2 - 3n + 1)^3$$

thus the ***first triplet***,

\begin{align}
a_4 = 9n^3,\quad  &b_4 = -9n^3 + 9n^2 - 3n + 1\\[6pt]
a_5 = \color{blue}{9n^3},\quad  &b_5 = 27n^4 + 18n^3 + 9n^2 + 3n + 1\quad\\[6pt]
a_6 = \color{blue}{9n^3 + 9n^2 + 3n + 1},  \quad &b_6 = 27n^4 + 18n^3 + 9n^2 + 3n
\end{align}

The latter two will yield different $a^3+b^3+c^3=(c+1)^3$ where **all** terms are positive for $n>0$.  For example, let the triplet $a_k,b_k$ as defined and $c_k =  \frac16\left(-3+\sqrt{12(a^3+b^3)-3}\right)$, then for $n=1$,

$$9^3 - 2^3 + 15^3 = 16^3\\ 9^3 + 58^3 + 255^3 = 256^3\\  22^3 + 57^3 + 255^3 = 256^3$$

I don't know why a parameterization for $u_1^3+u_2^3 = u_3^3+u_4^3$ will yield a *pair* for $v_1^3+v_2^3+v_3^3=v_4^3,$ with **all** the terms $(u_i, v_i)$ positive for $n>0.$

The next three were found by yours truly and based on,

$$(\color{red}{9n^3 + 6n^2 + 1})^3 + (\color{red}{-9n^3 + 3n^2 - 3n})^3 + (27n^4 + 6n^2)^3 = (27n^4 +  6n^2 + 1)^3$$

thus the ***second triplet***,

\begin{align}
a_7 = 9n^3 + 6n^2 + 1,\quad  &b_7 = -9n^3 + 3n^2 - 3n\\[6pt]
\quad a_8 = \color{red}{9n^3 + 6n^2 + 1},\quad  &b_8 = 27n^4 + 18n^3 + 3n^2 + 3n\\[6pt]
a_9 = \color{red}{9n^3 + 3n^2 + 3n},  \quad &b_9 = 27n^4 + 18n^3 + 15n^2 + 3n + 1
\end{align}

Again, the latter two will yield **all** terms positive for $n>0$. For example, let $n=1$,

$$16^3 - 9^3 + 33^3 = 34^3\\ 16^3 + 51^3 + 213^3 = 214^3\\ 15^3 + 64^3 + 297^3 = 298^3$$

And the 10th by Adam Bailey,

$$a_{10} = (3n + 1)(9n^3 + 15n^2 + 10n + 3),\quad b_{10} = (3n + 1)^2(6n^2 + 5n + 3) + 1\qquad $$

---

**II. Addendum**

There is a curious connection to Ramanujan's work. The two triplets are related by,

$$a_4+b_4 = a_7+b_7 = \color{magenta}{9n^2 - 3n + 1}$$

a polynomial which is quite important to "*real cubic fields*". The discriminant $d$ of,

$$x^3 + x^2 - (3 n^2 + n)x + n^3=0$$

is $d=-n^2(\color{magenta}{9n^2+3n+1})^2$. Since it is a negative square, the cubic always has three *real* roots $x_i$. Then we have [Ramanujan's nice identity](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1068084/4781),

$$x_1^{1/3}+x_2^{1/3}+x_3^{1/3} = \sqrt[3]{-(6n+1)+3\sqrt[3]{n(9n^2+3n+1)}}$$

For $n=-1$, we recover his well-known,

$$\sqrt[3]{\cos\tfrac{2\pi}7}+\sqrt[3]{\cos\tfrac{4\pi}7}+\sqrt[3]{\cos\tfrac{8\pi}7}=\sqrt[3]{\tfrac{5-3\,\sqrt[3]7}2}$$

---

**III. Questions:**

1. Can you find more polynomial solutions to $P(a,b):=12(a^3+b^3)-3 = y^2$, especially if it is a triplet? One may notice they seem to be based on $a^3\color{red}-b^3+c^3 = (c+1)^3$.
2. And why do some solutions manifest as a triplet? (For example, I can't tease out a triplet from Bailey's solution.)

Comment: Can you please give a numerical example of one triplet?

Comment: @user25406 Post has been edited to give a numerical example of a triplet.

Comment: It may be a new solution.
 $a = 12n^4+12n^3+3n^2, b = 24n^4+24n^3+12n^2+3n+1, c = 72n^6+108n^5+78n^4+33n^3+12n^2+3n$

Comment: @Tomita Thanks, but it is just a special case of the 2nd family $a_2 = 3m^2,\; b_2 = 6m^2+3m+1$ with $m=(2n+1)n$. I've had a similar experience with the first family, so now I check potential new families if they are just special cases of the known ones. P.S. I'm hoping for $a$ that is deg-$5$ with $b$ that is deg-$6$.

Comment: @Tito Thank you. I'll do it.

Comment: @Tomita I just found out there are _infinitely_ many polynomial solutions of the cubic/quartic type. See answer below.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After much effort, we can answer our question. It turns out there are ***infinitely*** many polynomial solutions $(a,b,c)$ to,

$$a^3+b^3+c^3 = (c+1)^3$$

hence,

$$12a^3+12b^3-3 = y^2$$

In fact, using our old friend $\color{blue}{k=9m^2-3m+1}$ from the post, we can find ***four*** infinite families.

---

**I. First and Second.**

Let $p = 9m^2,\;q = 9m^2+1,\,$ then,

\begin{align}
a_1 &= 9k^2n^3 + 9k p n^2 + 3p^2 n + (54m^4 - 9m^3 + 9m^2 - 3m)\\[6pt]
b_1 &= b_2+k\\[6pt]
a_2 &= 9k^2n^3 + 9k q n^2 + 3q^2 n + (54m^4 - 9m^3 + 18m^2 +1)\\[6pt]
b_2 &= 27k^2 n^4 + 18k(p+q)n^3 + 9(p^2+q^2)n^2 + 3(135m^4 + 18m^3 + 27m^2 + 1)n + (54m^4 + 9m^3 + 9m^2 + 3m)
\end{align}

In addition,

$$a_1^3+b_1^3 = a_2^3+b_2^3$$

Numerical example. Let $m=2$ so $k=31$, and $n=0$,

$$822^3 + (978 + 31)^3 + 22968^3 = 22969^3\\    
865^3 \,+ (978 + 0)^3 \,+ 22968^3 = 22969^3$$

---

**II. Third and Fourth.**

Let $r = -3m,\; s = -3m+1,\,$ then,

\begin{align}
a_3 &= 9k^2n^3 + 9k r n^2 + 3r^2 n + (27m^4 - 18m^3 + 9m^2 - 3m)\\[6pt]
b_3 &= b_4+k\\[6pt]
a_4 &= 9k^2n^3 + 9k s n^2 + 3s^2 n + (27m^4 - 18m^3 + 9m^2 - 3m + 1)\\[6pt]
b_4 &= 27k^2n^4 + 18k(r+s)n^3 + 9(r^2+s^2)n^2 +  3(27 m^4 - 18m^3 + 9m^2 - 6m + 1)n - 9m^3
\end{align}

In addition,

$$a_3^3+b_3^3 = a_4^3+b_4^3$$

Numerical example. Let $m=2$ so $k=31$, and $n=1$,

$$7401^3 + (21225 + 31)^3 + 1826583^3 = 1826584^3\\    
7648^3 \,+ (21225 + 0)^3 \,+ 1826583^3 = 1826584^3$$

---

**III. Remarks.**

Note that $(p,q,r,s)$ are related by,

$$p+s = q+r = \color{blue}{k=9m^2-3m+1}$$

But it seems "triplets" are harder to find, with the one found by Peter the special case $m=0$ of either pair above, and the one I found an isolated case (?).

**P.S.** A general formula for infinitely other $k$ has been found. See this post's [third answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4809327/4781).

Comment: Wow, it's wonderful!